# How to prevent Boostrap static-header's icon from being highlighted

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a static HTML header that contains icons.
One icon uses Bootrap's [navbar dropdown component](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default).

My problem is, when I click on the user icon and select one of the dropdown menus, the user icon is also highlighted (replicates in the attached scriptlet when you click on "D" and move your cursor down a little).

**How do I prevent the icon "D" from being highlighted after moving the cursor down a little?**

```css
<style> li.navbar-nav > a:hover,
li.navbar-nav > a:focus {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
}
.navbar.navbar-ct-blue {
  background: #1B96BF;
  border: 1px solid #1B96BF;
  max-height: 50px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar.navbar-ct-blue .nav-justified > li {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1%
}
.navbar.navbar-ct-blue .nav-justified > li > a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.navbar.navbar-ct-blue .nav-justified > li > a:hover {
  color: #00F2FF;
  background: none;
}
.navbar.navbar-ct-green {
  background: #1B96BF;
  border: 1px solid #1B96BF;
  max-height: 50px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar.navbar-ct-green .nav-justified > li {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1%
}
.navbar.navbar-ct-green .nav-justified > li > a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.navbar.navbar-ct-green .nav-justified > li > a:hover {
  color: #00F2FF;
  background: none;
}
.table {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<link href="http://themes-pixeden.com/font-demos/7-stroke/Pe-icon-7-stroke.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-ct-green navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-justified">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="pe-7s-timer"></i>A
        </a>
      </li>

      <li class="navbar-nav">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="pe-7s-note2" style="color: white;"></i>B
        </a>
      </li>

      <li class="navbar-nav">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="pe-7s-config" style="color: white;"></i>C
        </a>
      </li>

      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <i class="pe-7s-user"></i>  <span class="caret"></span>D
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" background="blue">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Logout</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Profile</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Jonathan, did you test my answer?

Comment: I think [`user-select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) may be useful too

Comment: Thank you S.Serp. I just tested your suggestion, I just made a minor tweak because in the actual live code, bootstrap add the "open" class in the '<li class="dropdown noFocusBkg">' element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply an inline style as `background:none` (or transparent) on last `a class="dropdown-toggle"...>` which is parent of your `D` element:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" style="background:none !important;" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  ...
```

**Edit:**

another way is to define a css class like as `noFocusBkg` as following and apply it to containing `li` item as:

```
.noFocusBkg .dropdown-toggle:focus { /*** new class to prevent highlighting */
  background: none; /* or transparent or inherit */
}

<li class="dropdown noFocusBkg">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  ...
```

the full code snippet:

```css
<style> 
li.navbar-nav > a:hover,
li.navbar-nav > a:focus {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
}
.navbar.navbar-ct-blue {
  background: #1B96BF;
  border: 1px solid #1B96BF;
  max-height: 50px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar.navbar-ct-blue .nav-justified > li {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1%
}
.navbar.navbar-ct-blue .nav-justified > li > a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.navbar.navbar-ct-blue .nav-justified > li > a:hover {
  color: #00F2FF;
  background: none;
}
.navbar.navbar-ct-green {
  background: #1B96BF;
  border: 1px solid #1B96BF;
  max-height: 50px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar.navbar-ct-green .nav-justified > li {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1%
}
.navbar.navbar-ct-green .nav-justified > li > a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.navbar.navbar-ct-green .nav-justified > li > a:hover {
  color: #00F2FF;
  background: none;
}
.table {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.noFocusBkg .dropdown-toggle:focus { /*** new class to prevent highlighting */
  background: none; /* or transparent or inherit */
}
</style>
```

```html
<link href="http://themes-pixeden.com/font-demos/7-stroke/Pe-icon-7-stroke.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-ct-green navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-justified">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="pe-7s-timer"></i>A
        </a>
      </li>

      <li class="navbar-nav">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="pe-7s-note2" style="color: white;"></i>B
        </a>
      </li>

      <li class="navbar-nav">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="pe-7s-config" style="color: white;"></i>C
        </a>
      </li>

      <li class="dropdown noFocusBkg">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <i class="pe-7s-user"></i>  <span class="caret"></span>D
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" background="blue">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Logout</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Profile</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you. This did it:
.noFocusBkg.open .dropdown-toggle:focus { 
  background: transparent;
}

Answer (score 0):

The highlighting is occurring on the `:focus` event. So you can prevent this by overriding Bootstrap's default `:focus` event, like so:

```
.nav > li > a:focus {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```